# How to link BrowserStack results (App Automate) & Azure Devops Pipelines for Android

Tags: android, azure, browserstack, browserstack-app-automate

I upload my android test apk and my tests into BrowserStack through Azure Devops Pipelines.

Once the tests are done, I need to know if the tests have passed or not.

I use the "BrowserStack Results" task:

```
  - task: BrowserStackResults@1
    inputs:
      browserstackProduct: 'app automate'
```

But I have this error:

##[error] Build not found by name: "azure-[Android ------] Hourly Tests-20220131.15"

[image]

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

​
Could you please let me know if you have followed the guide mentioned below while configuring BrowserStack on Azure:

https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/integrations/azure
​

​Along with this, please ensure that BrowserStackConfig is placed before executing your test script in your pipeline.

​Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give this in the browserstack capabilities for each browser

> build: process.env.BROWSERSTACK_BUILD_NAME